# SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query godaddy

Tags: laravel, timeout

Admin panel of my site takes too much time to load because of left joins.It was working fine before But now start giving error from last 2 days

**General error: 2013 Lost connection to MySQL server during query**

Here is the code in controller

```
public function admin_revisions(){
    $revisions = DB::table('revisions')
        ->leftjoin('requests', 'revisions.revision_id', '=', 'requests.revision_id')
        ->leftjoin('orders', 'revisions.order_id', '=', 'orders.order_id')
        ->leftjoin('payments', 'orders.order_id', '=', 'payments.order_id')
        ->leftjoin('users', 'orders.customer_id', '=', 'users.id')
        ->select(['revisions.order_id', DB::raw('MAX(revisions.revision_id) as revision_id'), DB::raw('MAX(revisions.updated_at) as date'), 'requests.updated_at', 'requests.revision_id',
            'orders.design_name', 'orders.order_status', 'users.first_name', 'users.last_name', 'payments.amount'])
            ->whereExists(function ($query) {
                $query->select(DB::raw(1))
                   ->from('requests')
                   ->whereRaw('requests.updated_at = revisions.updated_at');
            })
        ->groupBy('revisions.order_id')
        ->orderBy(DB::raw('MAX(revisions.updated_at)'), 'desc', 'revisions.order_id')
        ->paginate(10);
            
        $dates = $this->date_data();          
            
        return view('admin.revisions',['revisions'=>$revisions,'date'=>$dates[0]]); 
}
```

Can anybody help?

Comment: It's always recommended  to create VIEW in dB or stored procedures to fast your query. Poor database design lead to such errors. You can bring your data in chunk or limit your data fetching.